# Message Sensor can't detect/receive message

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

This may sound stupid idk but my message sensor can't seem to read the message sent by one of my actuators? I have a plane which plays its animation when a key is pressed and has an actuator which sends a message to my human with the subject "Earthquake". My human has a message sensor with the same subject. It is supposed to match right? Or am I doing it wrong? Replies will be very much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Yes the subject in the message actuator and sensor need to match, they are case sensitive and exact, an extra space will break it. Is the actuator sending to the right object? You can leave the object empty in the message actuator to have it sent to every object. Are you sure that it isn't receiving or is the actuator attached to the message sensor not working?

Answer (score 3):

In the first screen shoot, I have a `Keyboard` 
sensor, on the object ground plane, send a `message` to all objects (the empty `To field`) with a `Subject` of `somthing` (with the misspelling).

*Drag the images to a new tab to enlarge them.*
[image: send message]

In the second screen shoot, Now on the object `human`. There is a message sensor listening for a message with the subject `somthing`. When it receives a message (from any object) with the subject `somthing` the connected `action` actuator plays the animation.
[image: receive message]